# how to pass list of object to jquery ajax get

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm using mvc5 web api 
i'm trying pass multiple parameters to web api web method. 
i need filter result using this parameters
my code:
java script:

```
var options = {
 url: '/api/normdata/getdata',
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 data: [{ 'name': 'n1' }, { 'name': 'n2' }, { 'name': 'n3' }, { 'name': 'n4' }]
};
$.ajax(options).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
   var objectArray = [];
       ...
  }

function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
   var msg = 'Error retreiving data. ' + jqXHR + " " + textStatus;
   errorMessage(msg);
}
```

code in web api controller:

```
  [Route("api/normdata/getdata")]
    public IEnumerable<string> getdata([FromBody] List<object> somedata)
    {
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        var o = somedata;
        return stringList;
    }
```

problem is that somedata variable is always null
Please advise.
Leszek

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a `GET` request, but specifying `[FromBody]` in the controller. Try changing your request to a `POST`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Unfortunately after i have changet to 'POST' getdata method is not called at all. thanks. leszek

Comment: Any errors in the javascript console or network tab of your browser's dev tools? Any exceptions on the server? Do you have the `[HttpGet]` attribute on your action?

Comment: I have added [HttpPost] attribute and then the function is called. Unfortunately number of objects (somedata) =  0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var data = [{ 'name': 'n1' }, { 'name': 'n2' }, { 'name': 'n3' }, { 'name': 'n4' }]
var options = {
    url: '/api/normdata/getdata',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)

};
$.ajax(options).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
    var objectArray = [];
   ...
}
function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    var msg = 'Error retreiving data. ' + jqXHR + " " + textStatus;
    errorMessage(msg);
}
```

[Documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)